# Discovering JUnit5 parameterized test via class and method name throws org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException

Tags: java, junit5

I have sets of tests that I run to test the UI of various tools on my company's website. I built a system that runs these tests in different environments, and for my concern here, I wrote code that allows me to run a single test in these multiple environments. The problem is that when I try to run a parameterized test via MethodSelector (passing both class and method name as a String), I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Could not find method with name [TestTheThing] in class [tests.tool.fragments.TestClass].
```

I then tried passing the method name including the parameter, but then I got this error:

```
Failed to load parameter type [String param] for method [TestTheThing] in class [tests.tool.fragments.TestClass].
```

I've been researching this for a little while, but I haven't gotten anywhere, and would appreciate some help. Here's a mockup of the test:

```
public class TestClass {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("getParams")
    public void TestTheThing(String param) {
        // test code here
    }
}
```

And this is the actual code I use to find and run the test (all selectors from getAllTestSelectors are of type ClassSelector):

```
    // Runs a single tests in a fragment of a tool (used for batch-testing only)
    public void runSingleTestInFragment(String fragment, String test) {
        
        if (fragment.equals(""))
            throw new MasterTestException("Fragment name is empty");
        
        if (test.equals(""))
            throw new MasterTestException("Test name is empty");
        
        // Make sure test fragment exists
        String className = null;
        
        for (DiscoverySelector s : getAllTestSelectors()) {
            ClassSelector classSelector = (ClassSelector) s;
            String cname = classSelector.getClassName();
            String name = cname.substring(cname.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            
            if (name.contains(fragment)) {
                className = classSelector.getClassName();
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (className == null)
            throw new MasterTestException("Could not find a test fragment named '" + fragment + "' for the tool " + data.getAsEnum("tool"));
        
        // Create the selector
        MethodSelector selector = DiscoverySelectors.selectMethod(className + "#" + test);
        
        // Test that the selector is valid (will throw a PreconditionViolationException if otherwise)
        try {
            selector.getJavaMethod();
            
        } catch (PreconditionViolationException e) {
            throw new MasterTestException("The test method '" + test + "' does not exist in the fragment '" + fragment + "'", e);
        }
        
        runTests(selector);
    }
```

Comment: can you add JUnit dependencies from POM?

Comment: @ZakirHussain I don't use Maven, although recently have been thinking about changing that. Here are the requisite JUnit .jar files:

junit-platform-commons-1.7.0
junit-platform-engine-1.7.0
junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type name is not `String param`.

Rather, it has to be a fully qualified type name. For String that is `java.lang.String`.

When selecting your parameterized method by its *fully qualified method name*, if your class in the `example` package, that would be `example.TestClass#TestTheThing(java.lang.String)`.

This is fully documented in the [Javadoc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/discovery/DiscoverySelectors.html#selectMethod(java.lang.String)).